# React server side rendering only specific routes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, react-router, ejs

I currently have a website built using EJS and using express on the backend on port `3300`. The structure of the routes look like this:

```
localhost:3300
-/movies
   -/rating
   -/review
-/tvshows
   -/rating
   -/review
```

I am currently returning EJS files in the routes like this:

```
router.get("/:title/rating", function(req, res) {
    Movie.find({ movieName: req.params.title })
    .exec(function(err, foundMovie) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            console.log(foundMovie)
            res.render("movie/rating", { movie: foundMovie});        
        }
    });
});
```

But now, I want to add a new route in the structure that uses React such that the following will be built using React:

```
localhost:3300
-/documentary
    -/rating
    -/review
```

From my understanding, if I want to use React, I would have to re-write all my previous routes (that returns EJS) as React components since you can't merge the two servers (React and Express as they both run on different ports: `3000` and `3300` respectively). But since I have so much written already I tried to render the new routes on the serverside by following this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NwyQONeqRXA) resulting in:

```
router.get("/documentary", (req,res) => {
    Documentary.find({}).exec(function(err,foundDoc){
        if (err){
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            fs.readFile(path.resolve("./views/react/client/build/index.html"), "utf-8", (err, data) => {
                if (err) {
                  return res.status(500).send("Error");
                }
                return res.send(
                  data.replace(
                    '<div id="root"></div>',
                    `<div id="root">${ReactDOMServer.renderToString(<App />)}</div>`
                  )
                );
              });
        }
    })
});
```

And App.js looking like:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/rating">
          <h1>Rating page for Documentaries</h1>
        </Route>  
        <Route exact path="/review">
          <h1>Review page for Documentaries</h1>
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
      );
    }
```

I get an error:
`Error: Invariant failed: Browser history needs a DOM at invariant`

How do I fix the error? Or is there a better way to combine both EJS routes and create new React routes? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Issue

You need to use a different `Router` in the server as well.
Since `BrowserRouter` in the client React app cannot be processed in the server.

[Static Router](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/StaticRouter) is what you're looking for.

### Solution

Server-side rendering in `React` is very tricky. I recommend you to use [Nextjs](https://nextjs.org/) which makes it easy.

For `side-projects`, [refer to this blog](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/react-react-router-ssr)

Comment: If I decide to use Nextjs, can I easily integrate it into the current structure of my server?

Comment: It will take some time, but it will save a lot of headaches down the lane. Having set up my own server in a production app with `react`, I wouldn't recommend doing `server-side` rendering without Nextjs to anyone unless you absolutely know what you're doing.

Comment: will I still be able to use my EJS frontend if I decide to use Nextjs?

Comment: I've no idea about that one though.  You should refer to docs of Nextjs on that one.